# docker metrics reside in different location for different environment or versions

Tags: docker, coreos

I need to gather docker metrics like cpu, memory and I/O, but I noticed that on my Ubuntu 14.04 the location of the metrics are different from the location in my CoreOs system:

**For example:**

The docker cpu metrics in ubuntu are located under:

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/docker/<dockerLongId>/cpuacct.stat
```

The docker cpu metrics for CoreOs are located under:

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/system.slice/docker-<dockerLongId>.scope/cpuacct.stat
```

do you have an idea what will be the best way to support both environments?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous issues with this.  To start with the CoreOS vs Ubuntu part, this is due to the fact that on Ubuntu systemd slices are not used.

[man systemd.slice](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.slice.html)

In the end, control groups are designed to be configurable. At any given time a process could be reconfigured by moving the PID between different cgroups.  Inherently there will be a small amount of unpredictable behavior.  Those patterns should be stable for processes started by their respective init systems.

The best way to detect which method should be used would be to read `/etc/os-release`.  The purpose of this file is to provide a stable method for determining not only the distro, but the version as well.